# Are software recommendation questions welcome?

Tags: support, scope, questions

I came across [a question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288127/waiting-time-display-app-in-python) to review. I skip the review because I do not know what to do when software (libraries, frameworks, tools) recommendations are asked.

I checked the [Help Center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking), but I can not see this covered there.

Are tool recommendations welcome here? Or, like on Stack Overflow, are they not?

Comment: \*[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/copywriting/naming/) (with a space)

Comment: @PeterMortensen You know both of us evidently didn't notice the missing "f" either. "Overlow" vs "Overflow".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see this as a software recommendation question (which would be off-topic). This is a request for review, explicitly noting that if there is a library that helps doing it better they're open to that.